# Why is an .eps made in Illustrator glitched when I open it in CorelDraw?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, eps

I have download a .zip file that contains an .eps and an .ai file from a free website. When I imported them into CorelDraw x6, I get these glitches in the image, and it looks nothing like the example .jpg.

[image]

**Original Jpeg image**

[image]

How can I import this file into CorelDraw and get rid of these glitches and get a similar vector image as it seen in the .jpg?

Comment: It would appear that transparency settings in Illustrator are not supported in CorelDraw.

Comment: @Metis so what to do in this condition. Any suggestion.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a Corel user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only surefire way would be to open the file in Adobe Illustrator. As Metis mentions in the comments, CorelDraw and Illustrator are not very compatible. In this case, blending and transparencies in Illustrator are apparently not supported by CorelDraw.

Within Illustrator, you could try and export the file as an old version .eps or even .pdf and try and import that in Corel. No success guaranteed, though.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Like Jpeg a universal file is there any universal file so that it can support both software. I tried with eps and ai. No suucess

Comment: @ateks .eps is usually the universal format, but Illustrator can still embed things like transparency in there that won't show.up correctly elsewhere. I'm sorry, but there is a good chance that your problem simply isn't solvable. I don't mean to sound cynical, but you did  get this for free--you might've gotten what you paid for. 